# Numpy indexing using an array of booleans

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following array which indicates whether or not to take a certain item:

```
import numpy as np

test_array = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                       [1, 1, 0],
                       [1, 1, 1]])
```

The array I want to index is this one:

```
classes = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

This is what the result should be:

```
[['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: what have you tried? [ask]

Comment: I have retracted my duplicate flag, since this question is slightly different. I have posted what I believe to be the most idiomatic and straightforward answer, feel free to take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers I've seen so far range from awkward to, quite frankly, baffling, so here is a straightforward solution.

```py
import np

arr = np.array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]])

arr_bools = arr.astype(np.bool)

lookup_lst = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])

res = [lookup_lst[row].tolist() for row in arr_bools]
```

Answer (score 1):

---

I would start with something like that:

```
result = []
for row in test_array:
    partial_result = []
    for i in range(3):
        if row[i] == 1:
            partial_result.append(classes[i])
    result.append(partial_result)
print(result)
```

Results with:

```
[['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

In Python, we prefer list comprehension over loops, so time to improve:

```
print([[classes[i] for i, val in enumerate(row) if val] for row in test_array])
```

`enumerate` is an in-build function which takes an iterable object as a parameter and returns iterable of tuples (index, element) for all elements in the original iterable, so `enumerate(row)` will return (0, [0, 0, 1]), (1, [1, 1, 0]) and (2, [1, 1, 1]).

`for i, val in enumerate(row) if val` will work, because `1s` are interpreted as `True` in Python and `0s` as `False`.

```
[[classes[i] for i, val in enumerate(row) if val] for row in test_array]
^ create a list of elements based on some original list ------->^
 ^ each element of that list will be a list itself.
      ^ elements of that inner lists will be objects from classes list
              ^ for each pair (i, element) from enumerate(row) take this ith
                element, but just if val == 1 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
import numpy as np

test_array = np.array([[0, 0, 1],
                       [1, 1, 0],
                       [1, 1, 1]])

classes = ['a', 'b', 'c']

lookup = dict(enumerate(classes))
result = [[lookup[i] for i, e in enumerate(arr) if e] for arr in test_array]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as this:

```py
result = []
for array in test_array:
     result.append([classes[i] for i,value in enumerate(array ) if value ])
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line you can do:

```py
print ([[c for (x, c) in zip(l, classes) if x] for l in test_array])
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by matrix multiplication:

```
[*map(list, test_array.astype('O')@classes)]
# [['c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Comment: What does `astype('O')` means?

Comment: @DanielMesejo it converts to `object` `dtype`.